# Can I use require() function in a template file?

Tags: functions, templates

In my template file I want to include a library. I uploaded the library into my theme folder, and inside my theme folder is my custom template file. In my custom template file I have `require 'OAuth2/Client.php';` but when I load a page that uses the template, it gives me this:

> Warning: require(OAuth2/Client.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /home/healthf0/public_html/wp-content/themes/healthfitcorpwell/single-iframe.php
>   on line 4

Obviously the file does exist, I can see it sitting there via FTP. Why is it telling me this?

Comment: never use relative paths when you include php files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing this error because you are `require`ing the file with a relative path. As @Mark Kapulun pointed out in the comments you should not use relative paths when `require`ing files. Instead you want to be explicit and use absolute paths.

Use [get_template_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)  which returns the

> Absolute path to the directory of the current theme (without the trailing slash)

In your template file the require statement will look like:

`require( get_template_directory()  . '/path/from/theme/root/to/file.php');`

Or `get_stylesheet_directory()` if you are making a child theme. [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)

**Update:**

As @Jack Johansson noted in his answer, you may also consider using `require_once` instead. This will protect you from errors generated by multiple inclusions of the file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2418514/8015265) for more details.

Comment: `get_stylesheet_directory()` solved my issue. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but use of relative paths is not allowed. You always want absolute paths. This can be done as follows:

```
<?php require( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/OAuth2/Client.php'); ?>
```

`get_stylesheet_directory()` will return the absolute path where `style.css` is located for the theme. It will NOT put the trailing `/` on it though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_template_directory()` to get an absolute path to your template's directory. For example, if your php file is located in `/my-theme/OAuth2/Client.php`, use:

`require_once(get_template_directory().'/OAuth2/Client.php');`

Remember, DO NOT use relative or access the PHP file directly for security purposes. Also, you have to use this conditional in your `client.php` file to make it more secure:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit('No script rookies, please.');
}
```

This does not allow direct access to your PHP file.

I also would go with `require_once` instead of `require` to make sure it doesn't trigger any error if i include it somewhere else accidentally.